# sklearn - kNN - KNeighborsClassifier - FutureWarning

Tags: scikit-learn, knn

I have a simple code for kNN model. It works well but I can't figure out how to solve the FutureWarning

```py
df = pd.read_csv('https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBMDeveloperSkillsNetwork-ML0101EN-SkillsNetwork/labs/Module%203/data/teleCust1000t.csv')
X = df[['region', 'tenure','age', 'marital', 'address', 'income', 'ed', 'employ','retire', 'gender', 'reside']].values  #.astype(float)
y = df['custcat'].values
X = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X).transform(X.astype(float))
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split( X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 4).fit(X_train, y_train)
y_hat = neigh.predict(X_test)
```

This part of the code: `y_hat = neigh.predict(X_test)` returns FutureWarning:

> FutureWarning: Unlike other reduction functions (e.g. `skew`, `kurtosis`), the default behavior of `mode` typically preserves the axis it acts along. In SciPy 1.11.0, this behavior will change: the default value of `keepdims` will become False, the `axis` over which the statistic is taken will be eliminated, and the value None will no longer be accepted. Set `keepdims` to True or False to avoid this warning. mode, _ = stats.mode(_y[neigh_ind, k], axis=1)

I've found how to turn off such warnings
[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74406936/knn-python-implementation)
[link 2](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-fix-futurewarning-messages-in-scikit-learn/)

```py
# import warnings filter
from warnings import simplefilter
# ignore all future warnings
simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)
```

But it looks like I'm not clever enough to understand what should I do to fix the Warning instead of hiding it.
I hope on you guys, share your wisdom please.

Comment: As it says at the end of the warning, [sklearn.KNearestNeighborClassifier.predict() method](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/55a65a2fa5653257225d7e184da3d0c00ff852b1/sklearn/neighbors/_classification.py#L284) is calling scipy's stats.mode without specifying keepdims argument ([here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/55a65a2fa5653257225d7e184da3d0c00ff852b1/sklearn/utils/fixes.py#L111C42-L111C42)) . Hence it triggers the warning. Because the if condition in the latter I'd try updating sklearn if you are really concerned with it, as it should be handled already

Comment: *Lapsus*
You should upgrade Scipy to 1.9.0 or newer. Else you can tweak the scipy version in that if clause to match your own